# On rotation table cells do not take up the full width of the table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, rotation

When the app first loads the table and cells are correct. When you rotate to landscape mode the table cells look like they are still set up for portrait mode. When you rotate back to portrait the table cells are set up for landscape mode.

Is there any way to manage this in the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I spend for ever looking for an answer and when I break down I ask a question, then 5 min. later I find the answer.

Well here you go.
Hope this helps out someone.

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```